# Microsoft Graph in asp.net web forms access token expires - how to refresh tokens in web forms application and not MVC

Tags: asp.net, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect

I have an asp.net 4.6 web forms application (no MVC). I am updating the security in my application. I am using OpenIdConnectAuthentication to authenticate with our Azure AD. Then I pass the access token to Microsoft graph to send an email with Office 365.  My token is set to expire in 60 minutes.  I either need to expand the expiration to 8 hours or refresh the token.  Without having MVC I am not sure how to handle this. I am looking for help with direction to take and possibly code samples.

(I original tried to utilize an MVC sample and put it into my project using a Session Token class.  Once we tested with multiple users I believe I had a memory leak and it would crash in about 5 minutes.)

Startup code:

```
public class Startup
    {
        private readonly string _clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
        private readonly string _redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];
        private readonly string _authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"];
        private readonly string _clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager(),
            });


            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = _clientId,
                ClientSecret = _clientSecret,
                //Authority = _authority,
                Authority = String.Format(_authority, domain, "/v2.0"),
                RedirectUri = _redirectUri,
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                UseTokenLifetime = false,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { NameClaimType = "name", RequireExpirationTime = false},
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
                    {
                        // Exchange code for access and ID tokens
                        var auth = String.Format(_authority, "common/oauth2/v2.0", "/token");
                        var tokenClient = new TokenClient($"{auth}", _clientId, _clientSecret);

                        var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(n.Code, _redirectUri);
                        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
                        {
                            throw new Exception(tokenResponse.Error);
                        }
                        var claims = new List<Claim>()
                      {
                        new Claim("id_token", tokenResponse.IdentityToken),
                        new Claim("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken)
                      };

                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaims(claims);
                    },

                },


            });
        }
    }
```

SDK Helper:

```
public class SDKHelper
    {

        // Get an authenticated Microsoft Graph Service client.
        public static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient()
        {
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    async (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                         string accessToken = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("access_token").Value;

                        // Append the access token to the request.
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

                        // Get event times in the current time zone.
                        requestMessage.Headers.Add("Prefer", "outlook.timezone=\"" + TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id + "\"");

                        // This header has been added to identify our sample in the Microsoft Graph service. If extracting this code for your project please remove.
                        requestMessage.Headers.Add("SampleID", "aspnet-snippets-sample");
                    }));
            return graphClient;
        }

    }
```

Sending Email:

```
 GraphServiceClient graphClient = SDKHelper.GetAuthenticatedClient();

            string address = emailaddress;
            string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            List<Recipient> recipients = new List<Recipient>();
            recipients.Add(new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = address
                }
            });

            // Create the message.
            Message email = new Message
            {
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = Microsoft.Graph.BodyType.Text,
                },
                Subject = "TEST",
                ToRecipients = recipients,
                From = new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = address
                    }
                }

                };

            // Send the message.
            try
            {
                graphClient.Me.SendMail(email, true).Request().PostAsync().Wait();
            }

            catch (ServiceException exMsg)
            {


            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to request the scope `offline_access`. Once you've requested that, the `/token` endpoint will return both an `access_token` and a `refresh_token`. When your token expires, you can make another call to the `/token` endpoint to request a new set of access and refresh tokens.

You might find this article helpful: [Microsoft v2 Endpoint Primer](https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/). In particular, the section on [refresh tokens](https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/#refreshing-a-token).

Comment: Great!  I now have the refresh token and I have tested using it.  I just need to figure out the best way to check when it is expiring.